# Which language had the first scanf?

Tags: history, programming

As a companion to the question "[What was the first programming language to have 'printf'?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/10937/10260)", **which language had the first *scanf*?**

It doesn't have to be literally called `scanf`, but I am looking for the following:

- A procedure, subroutine, function, or statement with the purpose of reading textual items from a file or input device.
- Takes a variable number of parameters, at least one of which specifies the number and format of the items to read.
- As this is a "first" question, you need to specify the year such a feature was introduced.  I am *not* looking for every language with such a feature.

The C `scanf` appears to have been introduced sometime between 1972 and K&R first edition in 1978, so that's an upper bound to the answer.

Comment: To narrow the dates down a little, in the Unix world `scanf` first appeared in Mike Lesk’s Portable C Library, which was added [as `iolib` in V6 in 1975](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V6-Snapshot-Development/usr/doc/iolib/iolib).

Comment: Under what conditions does a library count as part of a language? (Honest question, I don't know the answer.)

Comment: @LarsH: I would considered a library that is delivered or installed with an implementation of the language to count as part of the language.

Comment: I don't know enough of the early history of COBOL to make this a definitive answer, but in COBOL you declare the format of a file declaratively in its data description, then you issue a READ statement, and it populates a record whose structure is defined by the data description. Arguably much more robust, though less dynamic, than what C has to offer. It doesn't do it with a variadic function call, but who needs that if you've got rich structured data types?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Fortran: October 1956.

See [The Programmer's Reference Manual for Fortran on the IBM704](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/ibm/704/704_FortranProgRefMan_Oct56.pdf), Chapter 5.

In the question about `printf` Fortran was explicitly excluded, but I don't see why it fails to meet the criteria of this question. The I/O statement certainly "has a parameter which specifies the format of the items to read," though the *definition* of the format was separated out, with the obvious advantage that identical format definitions can be used in multiple I/O statements without unnecessary repetition.

The format can be separated out in `scanf` by specifying it as a variable instead of a constant, of course.

Later versions of Fortran, which included character data types, allowed the format specification to be embedded within the I/O statement, if desired.

Comment: Maybe FORMAT should be disqualified on the requirement that there be an argument that "specifies the number ... of the items to read."   :-)    If I recall correctly, it's the *de facto* number of variable/array elements that appear in the READ that determine how many items are read.  "Not using all the FORMAT" is ok, and coming to the end of the FORMAT is governed by baroque rules of where to resume scanning.   I suspect Algol 68 has similar features.

Comment: @another-dave Well, `scanf` just replaces the "built-in baroque logic" with user-written baroque logic to loop around the `scanf` statement. IMO the real genius of the Fortran design was identifying a subset of the general formatting problem which was "good enough" to do something useable almost all of the time.

Comment: @alephzero: Were the formatting operations in FORTRAN processed as calls to variadic functions, or would they have required compiler logic to translate what looked like variadic calls into sequences of calls to functions that would each expect a fixed set of arguments?

Comment: @supercat I don't think the a compiler could have converted them into calls with a *predefined* fixed sequence of arguments, because (1) as another-dave pointed out, re-using the format items follows it own logic (depending on the format string itself) and (2) the number of input items can be read as part of the input data - e.g `10 FORMAT(3I5)` and then `READ(*,10) M, (N(J),J=1,M)` is valid Fortran. The first input data line contains M and the first two elements of array N, subsequent lines each contain the next three elements of N, ignoring any excess input items on the last line.

Comment: ... AFAIK modern Fortran run-time libraries use a function with just two arguments, i.e. two data structures representing that format string and the variables to be input or output. (I don't know the history of how this evolved over time, but note that modern Fortran includes arbitrary user-defined code activated by the FORMAT specification, e.g. to output user-defined data types.

Comment: @alephzero: On a FORTRAN implementation which doesn't have a stack, it would be impossible for a function to accept a variable number of arguments; the only way to have a single function call take care of an arbitrary input/output task would be to use the approach you describe for modern implementations.  FORTRAN has, so far as I can tell, always allowed a reference to an arbitrary-sized array to be passed as a single argument, but that's very different from how `scanf` would have worked in typical early C implementations which could read arguments off the stack without the compiler...

Comment: ...having to know or care how many words on the stack were in fact function arguments.

Comment: @supercat: re: *On a FORTRAN implementation which doesn't have a stack, it would be impossible for a function to accept a variable number of arguments* - I don't see this at all.   If your calling sequence is, say, a jump-to-subroutine followed by sequence of addresses of arguments (pass-by-ref), then I can imagine a number of ways to determine the number of actual-args, and adjust the return appropriately.

Comment: @another-dave: I should perhaps have added "without having to be given information about how many arguments there are".  An implementation expect each call instruction to be followed by a zero-terminated list of argument addresses, but that would make it necessary to either include that extra zero word on all function calls, and have all functions' return logic scan for it (which would I guess be possible, but impractical), or else process calls to variadic functions differently from calls to other functions.

Comment: Re "...obvious advantage that identical format definitions can be used in multiple I/O statements...", you can do this in C scanf too.  The format argument is a string, which doesn't have to be a literal string.  It can be a string variable (that is, '\0' terminated array of char).  You can even write the format to the string on the fly.

Answer (score 14):

I think the FORTRAN answer is valid within the terms of this question, but for orthogonality with the 'printf' answer, I think we need to mention Algol 68 again.

Algol 68 provided 'readf', for formatted input from standard in, and 'getf', for formatted input from a specific file channel.

The names given here are from the *Revised Report*, published 1974, but the functionality was present in the original 1968 *Report* under different names, 'out' and 'outf'.

In both *Report*s, these facilities were implemented as procedure calls, with **format** as a mode defined in the language, with its own denotation (i.e., a format was not just a string).

Comment: Here's a link to the definition of **format** in the Revised Report: https://jmvdveer.home.xs4all.nl/en.post.algol-68-revised-report.html#A34

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the real question shouldn't be which language "had" the first `scanf` function, but rather which language first allowed variadic functions *to be written in user code*.  That would have been possible in B, and I am unaware of any earlier languages that would have supported it.

Other earlier languages allowed programmers to supply an arbitrary number of arguments for items to be read, but the compiler would have known how many arguments were being passed, and generated code to handle that many arguments.  In Pascal, for example, `ReadLn(A, B, C);` would have been equivalent to `Read(A); Read(B); Read(C); ReadLn;`  What would have made the behavior of `scanf` different is that a B or C compiler could (and typically would) have been completely agnostic to the fact that the function needed special handling to accommodate variable numbers of arguments, and would have processed calls to `scanf` no differently from calls to any other function.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable -- but separate -- question.

Comment: I am unaware of languages prior to B that allowed functions to actually be passed arbitrary variable numbers of arguments.  Instead, compilers for those language would translate each construct that *looked* like variadic function call into one or more calls to functions that each expected a *fixed* number of arguments.  The reason I focus on the "user code" question is that compilers for C and likely B as well would have come bundled with an implementation of `scanf` well before such a function was formalized as part of a standard library, but I think it's fair to back-date language support...

Comment: ...to the time when a compiler vendor demonstrated for users how to achieve such functionality.  Having to copy in a blob of source text is less convenient than just `#include <stdio.h>`, but the reason the function became part of the Standard library is that programmers would often include a definition of the function and then treat it as part of the language, rather than writing purpose-specific functions to handle input parsing.

Comment: I agree that it's a significant development in computer languages, but it merits a separate question.

Comment: @DrSheldon: It seems strongly enough related that if it were asked as a separate question, it might get dupe-hammered with a reference to this one.

Comment: @supercat Lisp supported it since the beginning.

Comment: @supercat Don't forget that in the 1950s (and 60s) nobody was too bothered about standards and portability. The focus was on getting something done. There was a lot of truth in the "real programmers don't eat quiche" opinion that (particularly in Fortran) "every data structure is just a special case of a one-dimensional array, so what exactly is the problem that needs solving here?" The concept of `scanf` and `printf`  functions doesn't make much sense until you have file systems which abstract away the underlying hardware, which early versions of Fortran did not.

Comment: @alephzero: Of course, today there's no consensus understanding as to whether the C or C++ Standard is intended to avoid characterizing as UB any construct that programmers might need to use, or to avoid defining the behavior of any construct that some compilers might have difficulty processing in a fashion consistent with sequential program execution, thus leaving a large number of constructs which should be expected to behave identically on most general-purpose implementations, but whose behavior cannot be defined by the Standard.

Comment: I still remember when I first encountered C after having learned Pascal that the ability to write printf-like functions in user code without special treatment in the compiler convinced me to drop Pascal and stay with C :-) This is really a powerful concept.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner: It is a powerful concept, but maintainers of free compilers completely lose sight of the Spirit of C, especially the principle "Don't prevent the programmer from doing what needs to be done".  In Ritchie's Language, applications could implement their own type-agnostic memory management code.  Even if the Standard wouldn't require that implementations allow programs to recycle memory without releasing and reacquiring it via free/malloc, the ability to do so is useful for many purposes, and implementations intended to be suitable for such purposes should support such code.